# autoincrement column remembers its last value in SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

In one table I have a column that's an auto-incrementing primary key.

The problem is this scenario:

- 4 rows are inserted
- those 4 are then subsequently deleted
- insert a new row, and the the auto-increment column value is `5`

How can I get this auto-increment column to have value of `1`?

Answer (score 2):

An SQLite Autoincrement field will increment forever.It will not replace the deleted value.It will replace deleted value only if it exists maximum possible value.See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) . What you are trying to achieve is not possible using autoincrement field.You have to do it programtically.

Comment: can i programtically change this field or not ?

Comment: You can.just put it in insert statement

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using auto increment you can just use integer primary key it will work fine. Even if your row is deleted one by one, the next increment will be done properly. If you leave the integer primary key field empty, the max value of the row is taken and a `1` is added (it's like `max(value)+1`). It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

if we have a primary which is autoincrement, the value will not be same even if you delete all the existing entries. It will continue from where it stopped on last insert. if you want the primary key to start from 1 again, you need to **truncate** the table or delete & recreate the table.

In SQLite "truncate" command is not valid. You can use a "Delete from *tablename*" and "vacuum *tablename*" to reset the primary key count to start from 1. Please make sure there is no "where" clause in delete command.

Comment: i use "vacuum tablename" but it doesn't affect !! and if i use "Delete from tablename" my table won't be deleted ?!

Comment: "Delete from tablename" will only remove all the entries in the table.

Comment: i used this but wasn't useful !

Comment: You have to use both the commands. first delete and then vacuum. Then if you try to insert, primary key will start from 1.